# Listen for user location change from another view - Swift

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I have implemented CLLocation in my appDelegate to allow a single instance throughout my app. I am starting and stoping location updates and storing the locations in an array however I am trying to listen for location changes in my view controller so I can plot the course on a map however not sure how to do this.

My code is below.

viewcontroller.swift

```
if let loc = appDelegate.location {
   var currentLat = loc.latitude
   var currentLng = loc.longitude

   appDelegate.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   appDelegate.trackLocation = true

   // SETUP OUR MAP
   mapView.delegate = self
   mapView.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
   mapView.showsUserLocation = true

   let spanX = 0.01
   let spanY = 0.01
   var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: loc, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
   mapView.setRegion(newRegion, animated: false)

   if(!markStartLocation)
   {
       locationStart.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(loc.latitude, loc.longitude)
       mapView.addAnnotation(locationStart)
       markStartLocation = true
   }
}
```

appDelegate.swift

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
    var locationArray = locations as NSArray
    var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
    if (foundLocation == false) {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        foundLocation = true
    }
    self.location = locationObj.coordinate

    if(self.trackLocation)
    {
        var lat = Double(locationObj.coordinate.latitude)
        var long = Double(locationObj.coordinate.longitude)
        var coordinatesToAppend = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        trackedCoordinates.append(coordinatesToAppend)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I added an observer to listen for location changes then posted a notification.